# HttpStatus code 499 is not available in Spring HttpStatus class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-status-codes

I am developing a REST API using spring boot.
My requirement is "User initiates the process and user cancels the running process any time ".

When he/she cancels i am throwing a error message along with the http status code.

for this scenario i have decided to use http status code 499 .

but this status code is not available in spring framework HttpStatus class?

1.Why this status code is not part of the spring class 
  (org.springframework.http.HttpStatus) any specific reason ?

2.What is the alternate status code i can use instead of 499 ?

Status code 499 represents the client's API closed the connection before it gets any response.

Answer (score 1):

It's not available on `HttpStatus` because [it's not assigned in the IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml).

You can't resolve with `HttpStatus.valueOf` either, but many Spring APIs provide an `int statusCode` method parameter variant, so you don't have to provide `HttpStatus` everywhere.

Now about your use case, unless I'm missing something, if the other party cancels and closes the connection, there's no point in setting the HTTP response status since you'll never be able to write and send it - does it?

Answer (score 0):

The ENUM_CONSTANTS for HttpStatus class in Spring Framework does not have 499 status code defined.

[Check Documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html)

Although,you can try to create a custom status code for your controllers for your usecase as explained in the following tutorial

[Create custom status code in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-controller-custom-http-status-code)

Comment: my  question was why its not included in HttpStatus class ?

Comment: sorry,i dont know that..you need to ask the dev's of spring framework or raise an issue in their issue tracker