# Setting Httpstatus 499 for HttpClientErrorException

Tags: java, spring, junit

I was wondering if there is a way to set Httpstatus 499 for HttpClientErrorException. The reason I ask is because I'm trying to do boundary check in Junit and 499 is the end of the boundary.

Though, I have read that this status code is not supported in Spring Framework.

I have tried doing it like this.

```
HttpClientErrorException var = new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.valueof(499));
```

But trying will cause an error during JUnit. Please refer below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [499]
```

Comment: What kind of error does it cause? Please, specify all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to set it in Spring. According to [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#valueOf-int-),
you can use:

```
public static HttpStatus valueOf(int statusCode)
```

in HttpStatus enum.

The reason why status 499 is not in the list of enums is its absence in [the IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml)

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689284/httpstatus-code-499-is-not-available-in-spring-httpstatus-class).

Comment: I have read the QA that you have shared before. But that also didn't resolve my issue.  I have updated my QA content base on how I used it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using UnknownHttpStatusCodeException instead of the HttpClientErrorException, since base on its description, this is the exception thrown when an unknown(or custom) HTTP status code is used.

This solved my issue.